# How can I get notified only for new answer posts for a followed question?

Tags: support, notifications, follow-post

I know I can follow a question, but I was wondering if it is possible to only get notified if there is a new answer posted?

I would like to avoid notifications of comments, especially if I follow a lot of questions. I'm only interested to get notified when there is an *answer* posted. Is this possible?

Comment: @starball hmm there is no answer in this question so i assume the answer is there is no such feature? in that case my query is answered i guess but ofcourse the problem is not solved haha

Comment: Correct. Such feature doesn't exist yet.